# NightmareJs goto after evaluate

Tags: javascript, nightmare

I don't really get nightmarejs so it's probably really simple.
My question is why app is stuck on Facebook url and doesn't go to Google?

```
 var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
 var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

 nightmare
   .goto('https://facebook.com')
   .evaluate(function () {
       return document.title;
     }
   )
   .then(function(result){
     console.log(result)
     nightmare.goto('https://google.com')
   })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line returns a promise, you have resolve the promise first to the data. Simply add a `then()` in the nightmare promise chain.

```
    nightmare
     .goto('https://google.com')
     .then(function(){
        console.log("I'm done")
     })
```

Here is the full code with a better chain.

```
 var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
 var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

 nightmare
   .goto('https://facebook.com')
   .evaluate(function () {
       return document.title;
     }
   )
   .then(function(result){
     console.log(result)
     return nightmare.goto('https://google.com')
   })
   .then(function(){
     console.log("I am on google")
   })
```

And here is the result,
[image: Nightmare]